# Calling flex from a makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, lex

I would like to call flex to build a .l file, then call gcc to build everything.

I tryed:

```
comp:
    lex scanner.l   \
    gcc -o a.out main.c hash.c -I.
```

error:

```
lex scanner.l   \
    gcc -o a.out main.c hash.c -I.  
lex: impossible to opne gcc
/usr/bin/m4:stdin:2994: ERROR: end of file in string
```

and

```
lex scanner.l
<tab> gcc -o a.out main.c hash.c -I.
```

error: missing separator.

The lex.yy.c generate by lex has is being included in the main file.

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Comment: You need tabs before _both_ commands in the second example.

Comment: @Pedro Dusso - are you including lex.yy.c into main.c for convenience, i.e. to avoid having to write extern declarations, or some other reason. The lex.yy.c file doesn't have to be included in main.c

Comment: @gbulmer: yes, I notice. However, I am defining a initMe() function in the scanner.l c part. My main.c will be replaced by a generic one for automated test. How do I include the main.c in the scanner.l? Just adding the proper include and re-making it?

Comment: @gbulmer: yes, I just had to reorder the compilation order and fix the includes. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all: a.out

lex.yy.c: scanner.l
    lex scanner.l

a.out: lex.yy.c main.c hash.c
    gcc -o a.out main.c hash.c -I.
```

Comment: sorry we crossed. If you don't mind, I'll leave mine because your answer is incomplete. lex.yy.c needs to be compiled at some stage

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
lex.yy.c: scanner.l
    lex scanner.l

comp: main.c hash.c
    gcc -o a.out main.c hash.c -I.

main.c: lex.yy.c
```

The first rule set tells `make` that *lex.yy.c* needs to be rebuilt any time *scanner.l* changes and provides the command to recreate *lex.yy.c*.  The second rule set tells `make` that the fake target *comp* depends on *main.c* and *hash.c*.  If either file changes, then invoking `make comp` will cause a recompile.  The last line is a stand-alone dependency that tells `make` to consider *main.c* as dirty any time that *lex.yy.c* changes.  It will also force an invocation of `make comp` to create *lex.yy.c* if it does not exist.

Comment: I think the last line main.c: lex.yy.c might be incorrect; main.c doesn't usually include lex.yy.c. Are you thinking of the y.tab.h file, which is sometimes included in main.c?

Comment: I don't think there is an advantage (in this case) using the rule `comp: main.c hash.c`. Instead a rule could  make the program, a.out depend on all the sources.

Comment: @perreal - I don't think it has to be, see [GNU flex document](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Introduction.html#Introduction) "flex generates as output a C source file, lex.yy.c by default, which defines a routine yylex(). This file can be compiled and linked with the flex runtime library to produce an executable." main just needs to call yylex().

Comment: @D.Shawley: thanks very much for this very detailed info. I'm still not sure about one thing: when I tested it here, my a.out didn't update. Then I change the scanner.l to force a update, but still it didnt. What should I change to make it generate the a.out executable? I realy dont need the "comp" stuff, that was just my try :P

Comment: @perrea - I apologise, my mistake. I will ask the OP why they are including ley.yy.c into main.c

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslash, or add a semicolon (`;`) before it.
As it is now, the two commands are added together on one line, and executed as one long command.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the usual Makefle pattern is

```
a.out: lex.yy.c main.c hash,c
<tab> gcc -o a.out main.c hash.c lex.yy.c -I. -ll

lex.yy.c: scanner.l
<tab> lex scanner.l
```

This is wrong, because in the original code, main.c includes lex.yy.c

This assumes the original code is changed so that main.c does *not* include lex.yy.c

Without that change, this will fail because there will be two definitions of yylex(), one from its `#include` in main.c, and one because it is supplied as a source code compilation unit. I encourage folks to *not* include a .c file into another .c file.

In general, the convention is to use a different file extension (.i) for included source files which generate unique symbols and code.

Comment: I think this will cause an error, when gcc tries to link `main` and `lex.yy`, which contain separate definitions of the same function.

Comment: @Beta - you are correct, it would have two definitions for yylex if lex.yy.c is included in main.c. I always avoid including lex.yy.c, and always just compile and link it. I use shared header files to define types, functions and shared data. I like this approach because as the program evolves, I might want to refactor source code into new files. So I find advantages in having explicit headers to define shared symbols. I am hoping to discover why the OP is including lex.yy.c into main.c. TBF, if the problem is small, it barely matters, but my 'reflexes' have helped me, so I like to understand.

Comment: I have the same instinct and I think the OP should adopt it, I'm just pointing out why your solution might not work for him as written; one hurdle at a time.

Comment: @Beta - does that improve my answer?