# Flex + Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, flex-lexer

I am trying to create a Makefile that requires calling flex. Following what has already been discussed in this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770170/calling-flex-from-a-makefile) and in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Makefiles-and-Flex.html), I came up with the following:

```
klex: klex.o kconfig.lex.o
        gcc -o klex klex.o kconfig.lex.o

kconfig.lex.o: kconfig.lex.c
        gcc -c kconfig.lex.c

kconfig.lex.c: kconfig.lex
        flex kconfig.lex ;  egrep -o "[^A-Z(]T_[A-Z_]+" kconfig.lex | \
        egrep -v "^T_EOF$" | sort -u | \
        awk 'BEGIN{i=1 ; printf("#ifndef __SYMBOLS_H\n") ; printf("#define __SYMBOLS_H\n\n") } \
        { \
                printf("#define %s %d\n", $NF, i); i++ \
        } \
        END{ printf("#define T_EOF 0\n\n") ; printf("#endif\n") ; }' > symbols.h

clean:
        rm -f kconfig.lex.c *.o


clean:
        rm -f kconfig.lex.c *.o
```

However, upon calling make I get the following error:

```
klex.c:1:25: fatal error: kconfig.lex.c: No such file or directory
```

which means flex is not being called, thus not producing kconfig.lex.c. Any ideas??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is `kex.c` trying to `#include` `kconfig.lex.c`?  That doesn't seem right, especially since you are already compiling `kconfig.lex.c` separately.

And, if it is right, then you have to list `kconfig.lex.c` as a prerequisite of `kex.o`, otherwise make doesn't realize that there is an order dependency between these two.